# Fire this function once

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a site that has an intro div that takes up the entire viewport, with a nav menu directly underneath it.

I'm trying to create a function that hides this intro div once you scroll past it. I also need a function to scroll your browser to the very top as this div gets hidden.

---

I have made such a function but it creates an issue:

The part of the function that forces the scroll to top keeps firing, not letting you scroll past the div I'm using as an anchor. I've tried a few different solutions to get the function to only fire once per session, but I couldn't get any to work.

I'm asking is, how can I make this only fire once? Or should I try a different approach? `.postfold_container_01` is the nav menu container directly under the `.prefold_wrapper` div I'm trying to hide.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();    
    if (scroll >= $(".postfold_container_01").offset().top) {
        $(".prefold_wrapper").addClass("hide");
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    } else {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using enclosure to provide your function a Boolean "done" value, then using it in the if statement. Like this:

```
  var hideAndScrollOnce = (function () {
    var done = false;
    return function () {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll >= $(".postfold_container_01").offset().top && !done) {
          $(".prefold_wrapper").addClass("hide");
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
          done = true;
      }
    }  
  })();
  $(window).scroll(hideAndScrollOnce);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try simply changing your condition to something like :`if (scroll >= $(".postfold_container_01").offset().top && !$(".prefold_wrapper").hasClass("hide")) {`